# Changing table rows in react component by clicking button "onClick" with object property values from function returned result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

**Hello i am newbie in react and i have to finish a component. The idea is to take the file value from an input, do some operations and return result in table. The problem i am stuck in is that i cannot take the returned value(it is an object) from 'pairOfEmployees()' and fill in the table with its properties.**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function UploadFile() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ file: {} });

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const fileType = event.target.files[0].type;
    const file = event.target.files[0];
    if (fileType !== "text/plain") {
      window.alert("Your file must be text.");
    } else {
      setState(file);
    }
  };

  function inputValidation() {
    const file = setState();
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =
      ("load",
      function () {
        const isValid = /^\d+, \d+, \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}, \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/gm;
        const isValidForNULL = /^\d+, \d+, \d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}, NULL$/gm;
        const dataLines = reader.result.split("\n");
        let counter = 0;
        dataLines.forEach((el) => {
          let personData = el.split(", ");

          if (
            isValid.test(el) ||
            (isValidForNULL.test(el) && personData.length <= 4)
          ) {
            counter++;
          } else {
            window.alert("Your file is not valid!");
            return;
          }
        });
        if (counter === dataLines.length) {
          return dataLines;
        }
      });
    reader.readAsText(file);
  }

  function getObject() {
    const dataLines = inputValidation();
    let allData = [];
    let newData = {};
    let singleData = {};
    let id = 0;
    let arrayData = [];
    dataLines.forEach((line) => {
      let lineElements = line.split(", ");
      singleData["EmpID"] = lineElements[0];
      singleData["ProjectID"] = lineElements[1];
      singleData["DateFrom"] = lineElements[2];
      singleData["DateTo"] = lineElements[3];
      id++;
      newData["id"] = id;
      newData["line"] = singleData;
      allData.push(newData);
      newData = {};
      arrayData.push(singleData);
      singleData = {};
    });
    return allData;
  }

  function daysForPerson(line) {
    let isNULL = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/gm;
    let txtDateTO = line.DateTo;
    let txtDateFrom = line.DateFrom.split("-");
    let dateFrom = new Date(+txtDateFrom[0], +txtDateFrom[1], +txtDateFrom[2]);
    let dateTo = new Date();

    let days = 0;
    if (!isNULL.test(txtDateTO)) {
      dateTo = new Date();
    } else {
      txtDateTO = line.DateTo.split("-");
      dateTo = new Date(+txtDateTO[0], +txtDateTO[1], +txtDateTO[2]);
    }

    days = parseInt(
      (dateFrom.getTime() - dateTo.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24),
      10
    );
    return Math.abs(days);
  }

  function finalResult(resultArray) {
    let sumDays = 0;
    let daysWorkedOnProject = 0;
    let people = [];
    let projectID = 0;
    for (const [key, el] of Object.entries(resultArray)) {
      if (el.dayArray.length > 1) {
        el.dayArray.sort(function (a, b) {
          return a.duration < b.duration;
        });
        sumDays = el.dayArray[0].duration + el.dayArray[1].duration;
        if (sumDays > daysWorkedOnProject) {
          daysWorkedOnProject = sumDays;
          people = [el.dayArray[0].empID, el.dayArray[1].empID];
          projectID = key;
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      daysWorkedOnProject: daysWorkedOnProject,
      people: people,
      projectID: projectID,
    };
  }

  function pairOfEmployees() {
    let allData = getObject();
    let resultArray = [];
    let prID;
    let duration = 0;
    let durationObject = {};
    let empId = "";
    let result;
    allData.forEach((e) => {
      prID = e.line.ProjectID;
      duration = daysForPerson(e.line);
      empId = e.line.EmpID;
      durationObject = { empID: empId, duration: duration };
      if (resultArray[prID] == undefined) {
        resultArray[prID] = { dayArray: [durationObject] };
      } else {
        resultArray[prID].dayArray.push(durationObject);
      }
    });

    result = finalResult(resultArray);

    return result;
  }

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col-md-auto p-3">
          <form method="post" action="#" id="#">
            <div className="form-group files">
              <label>Upload Your File </label>
              <input
                type="file"
                className="form-control p-5"
                multiple=""
                onChange={handleChange}
              />
              <table type="button" onClick={pairOfEmployees()}>
                <thead>
                  <th>EmpID#1</th>
                  <th>EmpID#2</th>
                  <th>Project ID</th>
                  <th>Days Worked</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td>{pairOfEmployees().people[0]}</td>
                    <td>{pairOfEmployees().people[1]}</td>
                    <td>{pairOfEmployees().projectID}</td>
                    <td>{pairOfEmployees().daysWorkedOnProject}</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="btn btn-primary"
                onClick={() => setState(pairOfEmployees())}
              >
                See Result
              </button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UploadFile;
```

Comment: Two big issues I see: 1) your state management seems kinda off; `const file = setState();` will not work as you expect at all 2) you mixed up `.onload = function` and `.addEventListener('load', function` syntax but by sheer accident ended with something that will actually work (`(a, b)` evaluates to `b`), but `inputValidation()` doesn't return anything (and can't since reading the file is async)

Comment: To fix this, you need to have `handleChange()` set up the FileReader and read the file, then do all the processing in the FileReader's `onload`, then finally call `setState(processedData)`. This in turn will rerender the component and display `state` as table. You should definitely also take another look at how state works with react hooks, because your approach is severely off.

Comment: Here's a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-wind-ji1gj?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ChrisG Hello, i am happy for your help! I fixed the problem and finished the component! Thank you!